# Does a a.s. convergence of $X_n\to X$ and a $E|X_n|^{2+\epsilon}\to E|X|^{2+\epsilon}$ combined, imply a $L^2$ convergence?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Does a a.s. convergence of $X_n\to X$ and $E|X_n|^{2+\epsilon}\to E|X|^{2+\epsilon}$ convergence combined, imply a $L^2$ convergence $X_n\to X$ (namely, $E|X_n- X|^2 \to 0$)?

Or more practically:  Does a a.s. convergence of $X_n\to X$ and a $E|X_n|^{4}\to E|X|^{4}$ convergence combined, imply a $L^2$ convergence $X_n\to X$ (namely, $E|X_n- X|^2 \to 0$) ?

Comment: Hint: If $E\left[|X_n|^{2+\epsilon}\right]$ converges to a number, then there is a uniform bound $E\left[|X_n|^{2+\epsilon}\right] \leq C$.  This implies uniform integrability of $X_n^2$.  Use this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I was unable to deduce $L^2$ convergence

Comment: That gives you that $E|X_n^2 - X^2| \to 0$.  There are a few ways to finish here and I'm sure this isn't the prettiest.  One is to observe that $E[X_n^2] \to E[X^2]$.  From Cauchy Schwarz, we have $|xy| \leq 1 + (x^2 + y^2)$. Then $\left(X_n - X\right)^2 = X_n^2 + X^2 - 2XX_n \leq 2 + 3\left(X_n^2 + X^2\right)$.  You can finish with generalized dominated convergence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will also add that once you have the uniform interability of $|X_n|^2$there is a Theorem 4.5.4 in K.L. Chung's book "a Course in probability theory" that gives the result there is a full proof there.